# "Error changing compile SDK from 32 to 33"

Tags: android-manifest

When changing the compiled SKD from 32 to 33 "this in build,gradle(app)", errors occur in Android Manifest, like it doesn't recognize, example "android: icon", I change back to 32 and it's fixed, but I need to use in 33, since I need to update kotlin to 1.7.10 and compose version in 1.3.1-beta01, I am a bit enthusiastic in this world of programming.

[image: 1]

Comment: Please post the image as text, not screenshot..